# LibGDX: Action when touchscreen is pressed and action when touchscreen is released

Tags: java, libgdx, touch, pressed

I have a problem with my code at libGDX in Android Studio. **I'm trying to have an object perform an action while I press the screen. If I let go, the previous action should be aborted and a second should begin. When I press again on the screen, the second action should stop again and start the first while I hold down.**

I have unfortunately no idea how I should do this and the Internet there is unfortunately also no exact information about it.
This also means that I have no code, which I can show as an aid position.

I would be very happy if someone has a solution, or can help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an input listener which has a boolean value called touching. Then in the [touchDown](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html#touchDown-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent-float-float-int-int-) event set the touching to true. Again in the input listener in the [touchUp](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html#touchUp-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent-float-float-int-int-) event set the touching to false.

```
public class MyController  implements InputProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
         touching = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
         touching = true;
    }
    //.. more methods etc

}
```

In your application create this MyController and set it as the inputListsner with:

```
controller = new MyController();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(controller);
```

Now you can detect when the user is touching and do what ever action you need with:

```
if(controller.touching){
    //user is touching do touching action
}else{
    // user isn't touching do the non touchin action
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the solution by Abhishek Aryan works too!

Comment: This is more better way

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Let me know if this helps..

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the solution by Abhishek Aryan works too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way inside render method :

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){

    //whether the screen is currently touched.
}else{

}
```

or

1. You can pass [InputProcessor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#input-processor) implemented class inside `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(..)`
2. after then override `touchDown(..)` and `touchUp(...)` method of that interface,
3. choose flag or some other technique for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Tapped:**

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
//do something; }
```

**Untapped:**

```
if (Gdx.input.getPressure()==0){
//do something-else; }
```